# How to make filter and map functions work in FormGroup?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have simple formgroup and two inputs, I want these inputs to filter and map values that I put in them, but it doesn't work. I realise I've made a mistake somewhere, but I'm new to rxjs and I'm begging for help.

```
this.reactiveForm = new FormGroup ({
      firstname: new FormControl(null),
      lastname: new FormControl(null),
      email: new FormControl(null),
      gender: new FormControl('male'),
      country: new FormControl('japan'),
      hobbies: new FormControl(null),
      input1: new FormControl(""),
      input2: new FormControl(""),
    });
    const input1: FormControl = new FormControl("");
    const input2 = new FormControl("");
    const result$: Observable <any>= combineLatest([
      input1.valueChanges.pipe(map(value => value)),
      input2.valueChanges.pipe(filter(value => value !== null))
      ]);
        result$.subscribe(([value1, value2]) => {
        if (value1 && value2) {
        console.log('Filtered values:', value1, value2);
        }
      });
  }
  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.reactiveForm.value);
  }
```

Apparently I am missing something and making a grave mistake, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to react to the value change of the form control, you do it like this:

```
this.reactiveForm = new FormGroup ({
      firstname: new FormControl(null),
      lastname: new FormControl(null),
      email: new FormControl(null),
      gender: new FormControl('male'),
      country: new FormControl('japan'),
      hobbies: new FormControl(null),
      input1: new FormControl(""),
      input2: new FormControl(""),
});

this.form.controls.input1.valueChanges.subscribe(value => { // do something });
```

In your case - you have subscriptions on the wrong form controls, the ones which are outside of the `reactiveForm`. Since you want to combine the two Observables, it would be:

```
combineLatest([
     this.form.controls.input1.valueChanges,
     this.form.controls.input2.valueChanges.pipe(filter(value => !!value))
]).subscribe(([input1Val, input2Val]) => {

})
```